# how to make zurb foundation framework off canvas look flat

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Sorry for a noob question. I'm not good at css but how to make foundation framework off canvas look flat? It seems has a gradient at the very edge that makes it look like a 3D and I don't like it. Thanks for the answer!

I edited my question, added my code so you can visualize it.

I actually having 2 problems here, first, I want to make my off-canvas flat.. I searched through foundation.css all the elements with off-canvas and put it here. What do you think should I change?

and second is when I open this codes on mozilla off-canvas closes by itself everytime I clicked a menu that's link to an id.. but not in chrome..

this is my first time to try foundation. thanks again for the answer!

```js
      $(document).foundation();
 $(".sub-menu").hide();
 $(".main-menu").on("click", function(){
 if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
  $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle(); 
 } else {
  $(".main-menu").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(".sub-menu").slideUp();
  $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideDown(); 

 }
 });
```

```css
.sub-menu li
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.off-canvas-wrap {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; }
  .off-canvas-wrap.move-right, .off-canvas-wrap.move-left {
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; }

.left-off-canvas-menu {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  width: 15.625rem;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #333333;
  z-index: 1001;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  transition: transform 500ms ease 0s;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  -ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  left: 0; }
  .left-off-canvas-menu * {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }

.right-off-canvas-menu {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  width: 15.625rem;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #333333;
  z-index: 1001;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  transition: transform 500ms ease 0s;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  -ms-transform: translate(100%, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  right: 0; }
  .right-off-canvas-menu * {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }

ul.off-canvas-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; }
  ul.off-canvas-list li label {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.3rem 0.9375rem;
    color: #999999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #444444;
    border-top: 1px solid #5e5e5e;
    border-bottom: none;
    margin: 0; }
  ul.off-canvas-list li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.66667rem;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #262626;
    transition: background 300ms ease; }
    ul.off-canvas-list li a:hover {
      background: #242424; }

.move-right > .inner-wrap {
  -ms-transform: translate(15.625rem, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(15.625rem, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(15.625rem, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(15.625rem, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(15.625rem, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(15.625rem, 0, 0); }
.move-right .exit-off-canvas {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: background 300ms ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: -4px 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 4px 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1002;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
    .move-right .exit-off-canvas:hover {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05); } }

.move-left > .inner-wrap {
  -ms-transform: translate(-15.625rem, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-15.625rem, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-15.625rem, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-15.625rem, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-15.625rem, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-15.625rem, 0, 0); }
.move-left .exit-off-canvas {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: background 300ms ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: -4px 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 4px 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1002;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
    .move-left .exit-off-canvas:hover {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05); } }

.offcanvas-overlap .left-off-canvas-menu, .offcanvas-overlap .right-off-canvas-menu {
  -ms-transform: none;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  -o-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  z-index: 1003; }
.offcanvas-overlap .exit-off-canvas {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: background 300ms ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: -4px 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 4px 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1002;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
    .offcanvas-overlap .exit-off-canvas:hover {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05); } }

.offcanvas-overlap-left .right-off-canvas-menu {
  -ms-transform: none;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  -o-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  z-index: 1003; }
.offcanvas-overlap-left .exit-off-canvas {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: background 300ms ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: -4px 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 4px 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1002;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
    .offcanvas-overlap-left .exit-off-canvas:hover {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05); } }

.offcanvas-overlap-right .left-off-canvas-menu {
  -ms-transform: none;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  -o-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  z-index: 1003; }
.offcanvas-overlap-right .exit-off-canvas {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: background 300ms ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: -4px 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 4px 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1002;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
    .offcanvas-overlap-right .exit-off-canvas:hover {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05); } }

.no-csstransforms .left-off-canvas-menu {
  left: -15.625rem; }
.no-csstransforms .right-off-canvas-menu {
  right: -15.625rem; }
.no-csstransforms .move-left > .inner-wrap {
  right: 15.625rem; }
.no-csstransforms .move-right > .inner-wrap {
  left: 15.625rem; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.0/css/foundation.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body><div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas> <div class="inner-wrap"> <nav class="tab-bar"> <section class="left-small"> <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a> </section> <section class="middle tab-bar-section"> <h1 class="title">Foundation</h1> </section></a> </section> </nav> 

<aside class="left-off-canvas-menu"> 
<ul class="off-canvas-list"> 
 <li><label>Some Action</label></li> 
 <li class="main-menu"><a href="#">Main Menu</a></li>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
   <li><a href="#gohere">ID go here</a></li>
  </ul>
 <li class="main-menu"><a href="#">Main Menu</a></li>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
   <li><a href="#gohereagain">ID go here again</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
</aside>  

<section class="main-section"> 
<!-- content goes here --> 
<div id="gohere">
 <pre>












 Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.








 </pre>
</div>
<div id="gohereagain"> <pre>












 Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.








 </pre></div>
</section> <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a> </div> </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.0/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.0/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming an `unstyled` off-canvas as shown in the [doc](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html#basic), something like this should work.

**Updated CSS**

```
.move-right .exit-off-canvas {
    box-shadow: none;
}
.move-left .exit-off-canvas {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

***note*** make sure this is loaded *after* the foundation css is loaded.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8kqgLtm6/1/)**

As for the other issue with the sub-menu you have the following code in your example

```
<a href="#gohere">ID go here</a>
```

This tells the browser to do the following:

> Link to an element with a specified id within the page (like
>   href="#top")

But `FireFox` has a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=645075) related to using IDs in hash anchors. There are a ton of techniques to get around this on the web, but I did not seen any that would be a decent solution to post on this site.

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't change anything.

Comment: oh exit-off-canvas.. that works now.. thanks a lot sir :)

and about the firefox bug thing.. I am now sure that it's not foundation's fault.. thanks for clarification..

Comment: Actually I was looking into that issue and the navigation with the # works in my current FireFox version (34.0), and does the navigation, but it does cause the  off-canvas to disappear. I will update my answer with as to why here in a few hours. I think it has to do with the off-canvas losing focus or something simlilar

Comment: yes that's kind of frustrating.. it is working with my FF too, it goes to the link but off-canvas was forced to close or something.. do you think there's a tweak to fix this one?

Comment: hey dude.. have you found a solution? I tried this.. http://jsfiddle.net/8kqgLtm6/4/

I changed the position of off-canvas to right and it works good. so I guess foundation has an error with this. do you think this is a bug?